# Is there a valid reason about putting JS in the head of document?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, html-head

I mean : I know the JS is cached only if it come from a .js file. Also, 90% of my functions must be rendered when the page (html) is loaded (rendered), so it is better put JS before closing the body tag. (this prevent also to use document .ready(); and the loading of the page itself will be more faster).

So, which is the advantage on putting JS in the `<head></head>`? Expect the "order" of the code, which I don't mind so much to be honest...

Comment: _"I know the JS is cached only if it come from a .js file"_ - unless the whole page is cached...

Answer (score 3):

Placing a `<script src>` tag inside the `<head>` section makes sense – semantically. It does block the browser from rendering anything until the script is loaded but assures that an object (e.g. jQuery) is available in the rest of your code (in the body for example).

A common practice is to load a light weight script loading library ([HeadJs](http://headjs.com/), [LABjs](http://labjs.com/), etc) inside the head section, then load the *heavy* stuff lazily and/or on-demand.

Having said that, HTML5 introduced the `async` attribute for script tags and re-introduced the `defer` attribute ([docs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-script-element.html#attr-script-async)). So you now have a very good and valid reason for putting `<script src>` tags inside head sections because:

1. it makes sense
2. the script still loads *after* the page has finished loading

Comment: +1 for 'defer'. Semantically, <script> belongs in the header. Best of both worlds! FTW.

Answer (score 2):

The `<script>` tag causes two problems:

1. Everything below the script won't render until the script is loaded.
2. All components below the script don't start downloading until the script is done.

Putting it into the `<head>` only really makes sense if you need to execute some JavaScript before anything gets rendered.

So placing it as low as possible in the page would result in a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing about the elements in the `<head>` section are that they are loaded, before the `<body>` starts to load.

This is a very efficient feature, which are used a lot (IMO).

Loading of libraries, scripts, that have to run before the DOM has loaded have to done in `<head>` section.

---

> *I will give you a scenario*

Imagine, You needed to calculate the 30% size of the screen's total size and assign it to the element inside.

It would be foolish and wait for the element to load big, then run the script to load resize it again.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly more semantic to put it in the header, but it doesn't generally have any advantages. Sometimes it is necessary - for example, loading fonts using JavaScript (using stuff like Google Webfonts) has to be done in the header, or the page will render with the wrong font and then change, which won't look good to the user.